# Detail Object in a M-D relationship as part of M-J-M relationship

Tags: master-detail

Can a detail object in Master-Detail relationship be made master object in a M-J-M relationship (Master - Junction - Master). My opinion : No.

If answer to above question is No, can we have L1-J-L2(Lookup - Junction - Lookup) relationship and still have detail object in M-D to be L1? Something like M-D and then D(L1)-J-L2. If not, I may have to design my M-D relationship as lookup and have L1-J-L2 relationship for many-to-many set.
.
Please advise.

Comment: What's the actual question here? Have you attempted to model this relationship structure and run into a problem in doing so? This SFDC article: [Considerations for Relationships](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/relationships_considerations.htm) is probably also worth a read.

Comment: Could you draw what you mean and post it here please? That'll probably clarify your question.

Comment: Mark, I attempted to model the same in my org and looks like I can have a detail object as a master in another M-J-M relationship. I was having second thoughts on whether I should design my model this way or have L-J-L relationship instead of M-J-M for second one. But seems like I can have M-J-M relationship. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Wes, as of now I got my answer rectified by crmprogdev and Mark, if I still have any queries, I will try to draw something in detail for this issue and share here.

Comment: Curious to know why this question was downvoted. Although, I think the question had all required details given and I even got answers from Mark and Crmprogdev, I would like to know the reasons on downvote so that I can take care in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Vimal Desai, as shown in the link Mark Pond gave you, its pretty obvious that it is indeed possible for the detail object to be the master in an M-J-M relationship. Recognize that the "J" object is going to be a *custom object* and that one of the Master objects will be *primary* over the other. Based on that, there's no reason they can't both be look-ups from the joint *custom* object.

If you have any doubts about this, I recommend you create a Dev Org and try creating the type of Master detail arrangement you're looking for.

Comment: Yes Crmprogdev. I tried this in my org and looks like a detail object in M-D relationship can be a master in another M-J-M relationship. Thanks.